Flask simpleldap with multiple active directories
I started using flask simpleldap for my plotly dash app only to learn later that there are multiple active directories with different IPs for our different locations. Is there a possibility to introduce a list of hosts such that the app tries to verfiy the user/password at all given hosts?
I didnt find anything in the web

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
